# How to hook a custom user function to a wordpress core ajax action?

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development, actions

I need to call a 3rd party API when a permalink edit happens for a post.I found once an edit happens, it calls an ajax function with the core wp post action 'sample-permalink'. How to hook my custom function after this call is successfully completed and how to get the post details in my custom function ? Any help would be much appreciated .

Comment: Do you only need to call the API when the permalink is edited from that location, or _any_ time the permalink changes? If it's the latter I wouldn't worry about the AJAX request, and would try to make the request whenever the permalink is changed, regardless of how.

Comment: I need to call the API at any time when a successful edit happens for the current post permalink.